# Stackoverflow is being ripped without attribution in queryby.com

Tags: discussion

just found my stackoverflow [question](http://www.queryby.com/caught-in-restangular-promises/) in this site. with a lot of others. without answers. all the questions are attributed to one Rajesh Kumar .Also find an identical site named [querycom](http://www.copyquery.com/). thought you should know.